# How can I format my time series data for PyTorch LSTM classification?

Tags: pytorch, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, multivariate-time-series

How can I pre-process time series data for a classification problem and feed it into the PyTorch [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) model? I have the dataset like the below picture. How can I pre-process the dataset to feed it to the LSTM model?

[image]

Here, `event_type` is the target column and it's a binary classification problem. I want to train this dataset using LSTM.

Comment: Can you add a bit more information about what you are trying to solve and the rationale behind the fact that you want to use a LSTM?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76321333/edit). Thanks in advance. (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)